# Visual Studio Code Is Not Able To Launch Django Project From Debugger

Tags: python, django, importerror

I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE for building web applications using Python's Django web development framework.  I am developing on a 2018 MacBook Pro.  I am able to launch my web applications by launching them in the terminal using:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

However, I want to be able to launch my application through the debugger.  To try and do this, I navigated to the debug section, created the launch.json file, and changed my configuration in the drop down to Python: Django.  Here is are my configurations from the file.

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload",
            "--nothreading"
        ],
        "django": true
    },
```

When I try to run the debugger using the green play arrow, I get the following exception:

> **Exception has occurred: ImportError** 
>   Couldn't import Django. Are you
>   sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment
>   variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?   File
>   "/Users/justinoconnor/Desktop/Rapid
>   Prototyping/Projects/hello_django/manage.py", line 14, in 
>       ) from exc

Launching the VS Code debugger with this configuration should be the same as running python manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading, but it is not working.  I'm thinking it is because on the MacBook I have to use the "python3" command rather than "python", but I did not see anything in the documentation that would allow me to specify this in the launch.json configuration file.

Does anyone know how to resolve this so that when I run the debugger it automatically executes/saves my project?  I don't understand why this is not working when I can type python3 manage.py runserver into the terminal and it will execute just fine.

Comment: In VS Code try to do Cmd + Shift + P and write "select interpreter", you should see an option called "Python: Select Interpreter", choose it and wait until you get a list of interpreters. Select a python3 interpreter and see if that does the trick. (ideally select the python3 interpreter from your virtual environment)

Comment: Also when you run the debugger you can see the actual command, in the VS Code terminal, that is executed to launch your project, so you can see which python executable is used.

Comment: That is what I have done so far.  I started the terminal with "Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal" and selected the interpreter for my virtual environment using "Python: Select Interpreter" and selecting "Python 3.7.1 64-Bit ('env':venv) at "./env/bin/python".  This works when I am editing the code and type "python3 manage.py runserver" in the terminal, but not when I run the debugger.  Thanks!

Comment: Boregore, this is what I get in the terminal.  (env) US6749343-M001:hello_django justinoconnor$ cd "/Users/justinoconnor/Desktop/Rapid Prototyping/Projects/hello_django" ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" "/Users/justinoconnor/Desktop/Rapid Prototyping/Projects/hello_django/env/bin/python" /Users/justinoconnor/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd_launcher.py --client --host localhost --port 51054 "/Users/justinoconnor/Desktop/Rapid Prototyping/Projects/hello_django/manage.py" runserver --noreload --nothreading

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it's using the correct python executable. I'm kinda in the dark here, but try the following: In the terminal (with the virtual environment activated) run "python --version" (to verify the installed version in the virtual environment) and "pip freeze" (to list installed modules int the virtual environment and verify django install).

Comment: This is interesting.  In the virtual environment terminal if I type python --version I get 2.7.10 and if I type python3 --version I get 3.7.1.  Not sure why it is recognizing both.  It does not recognize pip, but when I run pip3 freeze I can see that I have django 2.1.3 installed.

Comment: That was what I was suspecting. Did you use python3 when creating the virtual environment? (like this: "virtualenv -p python3 venv") - that should make the virtual environment use python3 when "python" is used in the terminal

Comment: Did it work creating the virtual environment with python3? :-)

Comment: This worked! Turned out my python interpretor was set to another VE than the one I was actually trying to use

Answer (score 5):

Same issue caused to my VS Code environment even launching VS Code after activating venv (Python virtual environment).

The VS Code also displayed the Python Environment option "Python 3.7.3 64 bit" on the Status Bar. On first sight, this python environment option looks correct.

But, my issue resolved after applying Boregore's comment. Python Environment option related with **venv** python needs to be selected as an interpreter.

I selected the correct Python Environment option related with venv (in my case i.e. ~/.virtualenvs/djangodev/bin/python), by applying following steps,

1. Select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
2. Start typing the Python: Select Interpreter command to search, then select the command. You can also use the Select Python Environment option on the Status Bar if available (it may already show a selected interpreter, too)
3. Select Python Environment option showing venv path (in my case, i.e. ~/.virtualenvs/djangodev/bin/python)
4. Now, VS Code displays the Python Environment option related with venv, (in my case, i.e. "Python 3.7.3 64 bit **('djangodev': venv)**" on the Status Bar.
5. Re-run debug steps.

(Many thanks to Boregore for providing solution, this is just a re-elaboration of his comment to the actual question)

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `virtualenv -p python3 venv` (or replace "venv" with your virtual environment name) in the terminal to create the virtual environment with python3 as the default when "python" is used in the terminal (e.g. `python manage.py ...`).

The `-p` is used to specify a specific version of python.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I used the "python" command instead of the "python3" command when creating the virtual environment for my project.  This was causing the debugger to execute the wrong command when trying run the local server.  I was able to create a new virtual environment using the command ...

```
python3 -m venv env
```

... that the Visual Studio Code debugger was able to successfully recognize when debugging using the "Python: Django" drop down configuration.

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer too - will you be so kind and accept it? :-)

Comment: I'm relatively new to stack overflow.  Your solution is showing for me.  Is there something I need to do to "accept" your answer so it shows for everyone else?

Comment: You just need to click the checkmark-button on the left side of my answer. This will show my answer as the "accepted answer". It also gives me a couple of reputation points (like when I just up voted your question), which is what stackoverflow users are striving for. It makes your answers look more credible and also you get more access to more features the higher your reputation is. It's a nice way of showing appreciation for the help you have received :-) Also when you upvote an answer it will get shown before less upvoted answers.